# I am trying to add an event listener to a form in html using javascript but something keeps coming up as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

The goal is to add an event listener to a form that checks for 'submit' events to the initForm function, however, wherever I go to add the event listener, a certain piece of code keeps coming up as undefined.

```
let ShapeLink = (function(){
    //code here!

return {
        initForm: function(frm){
            //code here!

        }
    }
})()
```

could it also be affected by this piece of code that was in the script tags in HTML?

```
ShapeLink.initForm(document.querySelector("form"));
```

Where do I put the event listener? and what format?

ps here is the full HTML

```
<body>
<form>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <label for="shapeSelect">Shape:</label>
    <select name="" id="shapeSelect">
        <option value="">pick a shape</option>
        <option value="square">Square</option>
        <option value="circle">Circle</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="outputText"></div>
<svg width=100 height=100></svg>
<script>
    ShapeLink.initForm(document.querySelector("form"));
</script>
```

the goal is to put all of my code into the js file (the javascript at the top of the page.) i am unsure of what i need to do to define ShapeLink.

Comment: What is saying it's undefined? I assume you are getting an error message, so it would be helpful to see it, along with a more complete sample of your JS and how it integrates with the HTML.

Comment: it says that shapelink is not defined. and that is the complete JS, if you want i can post the full HTML

Comment: Yes please. We need to see where you're defining `ShapeLink` and where you're using it. It sounds like you may be calling it before it's been created

Comment: edited and added

Comment: Nothing in that sample defined the `ShapeLink` object.

Comment: ok so where do i define the ShapeLink object, do i define it in the let ShapeLink = function() or do i define it in the html?

Comment: Well I assume the `let ShapeLink = ...` logic is in it's own JS file? If so, just include that in your page. https://www.wikihow.com/Add-JavaScript-to-Your-Website-Using-HTML

Comment: i do not believe that it is. the only code that was provided are the pieces i have shown.

Comment: Right, but the problem is that you haven't included the first part (which defined the `ShapeLink`) in the HTML. This is why you get the `undefined` error

Comment: i am mainly confused about where i add the event listener and how to properly define the ShapeLink object, which does not show undefined until i add the code.

Comment: ok so what do i do to define that?

Comment: If you follow the link in my previous comment it takes you through it step by step

Comment: i have the script in the html, but those instructions are a little unclear on what i must do to define the function

Comment: also it i am required to put all the code in the js file